Why does this SQL function return a "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error inconsistently?
I'm hitting a strange issue with a SQL Server query, whereby depending on the server I run it on, it might error, e.g. one server the query will always fail on, but another it never will. The error is the typical error where a subquery returns more than one result and assignment or comparison is used:
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is the simplest reproduction of the issue I was hitting. This not the original code that was having issue, hence why I'm querying sys.objects, however it could be any table with more than 1 row that would be returned it.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SubQueryTest] ()
RETURNS BIT
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @allow bit
    SET @allow=0

    SELECT @allow=1
    FROM sys.objects

    RETURN @allow
END
GO

SELECT dbo.SubQueryTest()
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.SubQueryTest
GO

A SQL Server version where it errors (although I'm not suggesting it is definitely version related):
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5035434) - 15.0.2110.4 (X64)
Could it be some SQL Server configuration setting? I've not been able to identify one that's relevant so far.

There aren't even 16 lines in the UDF, are you sure you're invoking the right one? Also 15.0.2110.4 is quite an old GDR version of SQL Server 2019. There have been numerous cumulative updates that fix bugs to do with scalar UDF inlining, have you tried the same code and tests on a newer version in case you're encountering such bugs?

It's an inlining issue. If you updated your code, you wouldn't get the problem (as the function wouldn't be inlined). Alternatively, because you shouldn't be doing it anyway, don't try to assign an entire dataset to a scalar variable (and then the function can properly inline).

Thanks for the responses. Indeed, it's a straight copy & paste of the code I posted, so it is that code that causes the error. Knowing it may relate to "scalar UDF inlining" helps narrow it down. I completely agree that the code is flawed, but the original issue is present in production code, so I'm keen to understand the root cause before deploying changes.

If you update to the latest CU build you'll find inlining is disabled on this function because of this issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/0uPO7Buy See also https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2022-and-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16
